# Windows 10 system and compressed memory DISK usage 99%

Tags: hard-drive

Windows 10 system and compressed memory DISK usage 99% the only thing that shown task manager from control panel. Any ideas on why and how to fix.

Comment: Have you updated it? I believe there was a bug that caused this which can be resolved by updating the system.

Answer (score 0):

1. As @Hatsune Vocaloid Miku stated, [MS suggests updates could fix this issue.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/system-and-compressed-memory-100-disk-usage/aebcd95f-41b0-42f8-b426-f523535a6235?auth=1)
2. MS [also suggests OneDrive might be the cause of the issue.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/system-and-compressed-memory-service-high-cpu/421c32bd-e65b-4339-9473-db775e50096a) An effective way to turn off egregious MS communication with a Windows 10 PC is with a third-party tool such as [ShutUp10](https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10) and [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/shutup10/). You can shut off OneDrive, Telemetry (which reports on your PC to MS), MS SpyNet, sharing of your personal data etc., all of which consume bandwidth and CPU time. Use caution with these tools! First create a disk image or at least a system restore point before using any of them, because it might be difficult to return to the default settings if need be. Also note that one or two of these tools come with adware (OpenCandy).
3. [A thread On the Reddit TechSupport board states that turning off *Notifications* and *tips about Windows* might remedy your issue.](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/3h4wjg/windows_10_high_disk_usage_100_ive_seen_a_thread/) Press <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, type

   > ms-settings:notifications

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to get to the MS settings CPL:

[image: Turn off Notifications]

Sorry that there does not seem to be one sure way to fix the issue -- apparently Microsoft has given us multiple ways to access this bug.